# Best Practice in OData for exceptions

Tags: c#, wcf, odata, wcf-data-services

We are consuming OData service using dot-net.

When any exception throws in the odata service code or any business logic problem fails, service code handles that exception or error and return dotnet consumer a new error object with that error details.

Is it good way of doing as I am thinking it should throw an exception and at consuming end I should handle it in my own way.

What are your suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Both are OK. In both cases you need a specific manner to transfer the service status and error info:

```
// First case - the returned object contains status and error info.
IResponse response = OData.Serve();
if (response.Status == Status.Ok)
    ManageResponse(response );
else 
    ManageError(response.Status, response.Error);

// Second case - service rises an exception.
IResponse response;
try
{
    response = OData.Serve();
    ManageResponse(response);
}
catch (ODataException e)
{
    ManageError(e.Status, e.Error);
}

// Third case: Service returns correct response or null.
// In case of error Service contains error info.
IResponse response = OData.Serve();
if (response != null)
    ManageResponse(response);
else
    ManageError(OData.LastError);
```

Comment: Thanks Miroslav for your response.

Comment: Second case is fine. I am implementing in that way only but right now that is the case only when odata will throw the exception.

Comment: First Case: Response Status is always OK. When service has some internal error/exception they handle that exception and create one object which contains the error details and send back to client. Then client has to read or parse that object to check for the error. Is it a right approach ?

Comment: In case of error, the service must return object with correct status. It must not be Ok. However, if the service is third party software, you don't have other options. ... I'll another example.

Comment: Do you have any link which will say exactly how to propagate exception to client in case of odata ?

Comment: @user2463514 I suggest you take a look at the OData format specs. For example, [here](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v3-documentation/json-verbose-format/#66_Representing_Errors_in_a_Response) is how errors are represented in JSON. Note that this will [change](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/cs01/odata-json-format-v4.0-cs01.html#_Toc365464725) in OData 4.0. These messages may be represented by [`DataServiceException`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.dataserviceexception%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) which the framework will serialize.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try something like this also :

```
            try
            {
               //your Odata query and response code 
            }
            catch (DataServiceClientException dsce)
            {
                logger.WarnFormat("Client Exception, Status Code - {0}", dsce.StatusCode.ToString());
            }
            catch (DataServiceRequestException dsre)
            {
                logger.WarnFormat("Request Exception - {0}", dsre.Message);
            }
            catch (DataServiceQueryException dsqe)
            {
                logger.WarnFormat("Query Exception, Status code - {0}", dsqe.Response.StatusCode.ToString());
            }
```

Hope it helps :)